# Paged collections in Backbone.js

Tags: sorting, collections, pagination, backbone.js

What is the standard approach for paged collections in Backbone.js ? And how about sorting ? Does it support these features out of the box ? Do I need some sort of plugin ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of these things are supported out of the box (Backbone is a thin library, not a big framework).

For pagination check [Backbone JS Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865097/backbone-js-pagination/7874852#7874852)

For sorting, the think you have in Backbone is defining a comparator on a collection: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-53

So one approach would be to initialize your collection, and then when you have to change the order, change it's comparator and call collection.sort. This would trigger a `reset` event that you can listen for in your view and re-render.

Comment: This would work as long as the collection contained the entirety of the data set, which one of the two pagination methods is not in support of.   Sorting of non-fully-downloaded data must happen on the server side, unless you're just looking to sort "this page".